# How to disable/delete photo wall at QNAP login screen?

Tags: qnap

I don't like having pictures displayed at the login screen of my QNAP NAS.

In the manual I couldn't find how to disable/delete/hide these photo-wall at the logon screen:
[image: QNAP TS-212P Welkom scherm met fotomuur]

As a uBlock user a way to hide the photo wall, is by adding this rule:

```
###photo-wall > div#gallery > div.body.clearfix
```

How can the QNAP photo wall be deleted instead of hidden?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Control Panel ➟ System Settings ➟ General Settings ➟ Login Screen

In the QNAP "Control Panel", "System Settings", "General Settings", "Login Screen", there is an option to:

> Select one of the templates below for the login screen

It is just a matter of selecting the left image:
[image: QNAP Control Panel Login Screen settings] 
and the photo wall is gone from the QNAP login screen.

---

*PS I am still wondering why it took me 3 times (read: so long) to spot the setting to disable the QNAP/QTS 4.2.3 photo wall.*